# Problem editing checked out word document from sharepoint offline

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office

I have a sharepoint server (WSS 3) set up which users log into from their PC with a user name and password (so no NT authentication). They can then go to a document library and check out a Word 2007 file for editing in Word 2007.

If I then go directly to the document (which is now in Sharepoint Drafts under My Documents), I can open it (it requires authentication again). I can then edit the document and save it and close it.

If I then go back to the document library and do a check in, I get an error that "**This document was checked out to your local drafts Folder but the local copy could not be found or is on a different computer. Upload the local changes or discard your checkout to continue editing."**

The document is on the PC and is in the drafts folder where it was originally put.

One thing I've noticed is that after I go into Word and authenticate, a registry key to do with the offline files disappears.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Does this just happen on one computer, or to all users? Also, what happens if you just use the "Edit in Microsoft Office Word" option on a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using forms-based authentication?  If so, make sure you have Service Pack 2 loaded, as it made some big changes related to Office Client integration.  From TechNet: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201.aspx

*If you have not installed Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 with Service Pack 2 (SP2), client integration is disabled by default when you use forms-based authentication. This is because client integration does not natively support forms-based authentication prior to Office SharePoint Server 2007 with SP2. When client integration is disabled, links to client applications are not visible and documents cannot be opened in client applications; documents can only be opened in a Web browser. However, users can download documents, edit them in client applications locally, and then upload them to the site.
If you have installed Office SharePoint Server 2007 with SP2, client integration client integration is supported for Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and SharePoint Designer authoring.*

Actually, now that I think about it, the answer might actually be even easier.  What happens if you navigate to the SharePoint drafts folder, open the document, and then check it in directly from within Word (as opposed to checking it in from the SharePoint UI)?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint SP2 Update is released and ready for download. You can check the article here.
http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/06/microsoft-sharepoint-server-2007.html